# How can I print the structure of an object?

Tags: c#, .net

object have all the properties of class xmlparser and datalog_session.
Now I need to print all the properties of and object dts on richtextbox.
What should I do?

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "XML files|*.xml";
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    txtPath.Text = ofd.FileName;
    XMLParser objxmlparser = new XMLParser();
    ArrayList al = objxmlparser.readDataLogXml(txtPath.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i <al.Count ; i++)
    {
        //Getting Object of DataLog_Session
        Datalog_Session dts = (Datalog_Session)al[i];

        //
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.BaseID);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.TWA_Time_Base.ToString());
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.User);
        //richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.Time_Stamp);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.Recording_Interval.ToString());
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.Comments);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.Reason_Code.ToString());
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.Session_Number.ToString());
        richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.SN);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write an extension method for Datalog_Session class, which will return desired format.

Comment: already method written in datalog_session() in datalogSession class which return the same format to print on richtextbox

Comment: So I guess you can call that method to append the text in the for loop, can't you?

Comment: appended the same in richtextbox by using for loop with object of Datalog_Session class

Answer (score 1):

You should override a [`.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method for your class.

```
public class Datalog_Session
{
    // ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Value for foo: {0}, value for bar: {1}",
           this.foo, this.bar)
    }
}
```

Then in your code

```
Datalog_Session dts = (Datalog_Session)al[i];

richTextBox1.AppendText(dts.ToString());
```